# What's the best way to copy two binary files in QT

Tags: qt, binary, file-copying

I want to copy one binary file to another binary file.
The only constraint I have is that copying must occur through the `QFile` (because I've overloaded some internal methods and I need them to run).
I wrote a naive way to solve but is a slow writer:

```
QFile * write_to = new QFile("myfile.bin");
if(write_to->open(QFile::WriteOnly))
{
    QFile read_from("my_outher_bin.bin");
    if(read_from.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QDataStream write_data(write_to);
        QDataStream read_data(&read_from);

        while(write_to->size() < read_from.size())
            write_data << read_data;         
   }
}
```

What is the most effective way to do this?

Comment: Why not [QFile::copy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy) ? What internal methods have you changed?

Comment: i change the read and write methods to add encryption and decryption on file

Comment: What is the file sizes ?

Comment: 800mb to 5gb (it can be read first to memory (im on 64bit windows) but i think it's not the most efficient way)

Comment: Looking at the [code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qfile.cpp#n810) of `QFile::copy` it still seems to use the `read`and `write` methods and if that doesn't work copy the code and do something similar (they use a 4k byte buffer and copy the data in chunks).

Comment: @xander he wants to manipulate the data before copy(write).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy and safe way to do it, use the STD libraries, [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) is a good option:

```
std::ifstream  src("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream  dst("to_file.txt",   std::ios::binary);
dst << src.rdbuf();
```

If you are using C++17, you can use the <[filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)> extension and use the [fs::copy_file](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) function.

```
fs::copy_file("file.txt", "to_file.txt");
```

Comment: They are looking for a way to do it with QFile because they are overloading some internal methods

Comment: What is the problem? You can still use this function, you have access to the complete file name or path.